# RNG Distribution with multiple instances

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, random, cryptography

If I need to generate random 8 bytes with `RandomNumberGenerator` class, I can generate all 8 bytes with a single instance and also I can use two instances of `RandomNumberGenerator` to generate 8 bytes - first one will generate 4 bytes and the second one will generate remaining 4 bytes. Question is - if I use two instances of `RandomNumberGenerator` will it make some any of 8 bytes more probable than others? Will it be a secure generator?

Comment: `RandomNumberGenerator` generates *uniformly distibuted* and *independent* (with `0` correlation) random values. That's why it doesn't matter if you have one or several generators

Comment: Have you tried running the two cases, perhaps for 24 hours each, and testing whether the two outputs have the randomness you would expect?

Comment: No machine generated random sequence is truly random.  The only real random generators are base on Nature.  In theory if you have a true random generator there should be no difference in probability of using a single 8 bit generator or using two 4 bit generators to create the results.  So this may be a trick question.

Comment: I will try to run both cases and write down histogram of frequencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RandomNumberGenerator is a crypto-secure random generator, so generating two bits with one instance should be just as secure as generating one bit with two instances.

Comment: Technically, there is no proof for any PRG to be secure PRG.

Comment: If you're talking mathematically, sure. RandomNumberGenerator does say it's for "cryptographic random number generators".

Comment: Yes, that is the correct term i.e. it is for cryptographic purposes, not like _crypto-secure random generator_